# Autoloading package that contains Class of same name as imported class

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have a project that includes a PHP file that defines a class named `Response` and I'm auto-loading Guzzle via composer (which also defines it's own `Response` class)

The question is do I run the risk that PHP might get confused as to which `Response` class it should use? If I use `Response` by itself I don't run the risk that it will somehow fetch the Guzzle class unless I do a `use` statement right?

I think it's fine unless I do the `use` statement but I just wanna be sure.

Comment: Basicly not as long as the classes got own, unique namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any risk of conflicts, that's why [PHP Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) exist!
Although the *short name* of both classes are the same, their *FQCN* (Fully Qualified Class Name) are different, so there's no chance of getting confused.

Guzzle's `Response` class is:

```
\Guzzle\Http\Message\Response
```

Your class would be something like:

```
\MyApp\Response
```

(or just `\Response` if you didn't set a namespace for it, which is a very bad practise!)

You can `use` either of them in your classes, or even both, as long as you set an alias for one of them:

```
use \MyApp\Response;
use \Guzzle\Http\Message\Response as GuzzleResponse;

// ...

$myResponse = new Response();
$guzzleResponse = new GuzzleResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the classes got individual namespaces.

Composer (and its autolaoder) will resolve the namespace with the classname.
So if you use your own class ("Class1") and the foreign class ("Class2") with the same classname ("Classname") with different namespaces e.g.

`namespace \Me\MyPackage\Classname`

`namespace \Guzzle\Classname`

you will be fine. If you wanna create an instance of one of the classes just type the full qualified namespace e.g.

`$var1 = new \Me\MyPackage\Classname();`